# Cucumber - Feature file with page object model approach

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-objects, cucumber, maven

I am totally new to cucumber, I am using page object model approach.

Let's say I have 3 page and 3 test classes

Ex: login Page.java / loginTest.java

Registration Page.java/Registration Test.java

ContactPage.java/ContactTest.java

Question(doubt): Do I need to create a 3 separate feature file?
If not then how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Short and incomplete answer:

No, you don't. Technically, you can write how you want - the Cucumber engine just calls method based on steps regex, it doesn't deal with the Scenarios organization in files.

Long and deeper answer:

(Paste short answer here).
Additionally, it is necessary to have a better understanding of the purpose of BDD and Page Objects.

Regarding BDD, I would point to [Dan North's article](https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) and [this post of

Aslak Hellesøy](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10194242) and the article [3 misconceptions about BDD](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/3-misconceptions-about-bdd).

With the above-mentioned knowledge, one can understand that Page Objects is just a design pattern, completely unrelated to BDD and Cucumber. The techniques are often used together, but one needs always to justify its usage on a given project, not using it as a single silver-bullet tool out-of-the-box.